# Play Store Keeps Loading After Switching Google Account

Tags: google-play-store, google-account

I removed a Google account and added a new one. Now when I go to Play Store > My apps > It just keeps loading. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Did you try to clear the Google Play app's data and cache? Sometimes it does task in the background such as updating Google services and if your network is slow, nothing will show up until it finishes.

Comment: @esQmo_ nope, should I do that?

Comment: That's where you start first. So yeah you should

Comment: @esQmo_ ok I just did it, it's still loading but I let it sit for a while. I will update after a few hours.

Comment: I think it's just doing some background task. You should have a stable network connection btw. And preferably use your WiFi network.

Comment: @esQmo_ I tried something: I installed a new app, the loading issue went away after it. Now my question is: The old apps from the old account is still in the phone but not the Play Store anymore, should I uninstall/reinstall those apps?

Comment: The old won't appear in Play Store simply because you removed the account that had installed them. It's something like an history. It's up to you whether to keep those apps om your phone or remove them then install using your account.

Comment: You   should answer your question and mark it as solved so other people having similar issues can find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the eternal loading issue by simply installing a new app (any app).